# How to count if a cell contains a specific number

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to check whether column C contains a specific year. I have tried this formula with no luck. I am returning 1 when it should be 12.

I have also tried changing my compare value to 2022. Same result.

`=COUNTIF(C3:C38,"*"&K3&"*")`

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

[image: Click link to see screenshot of example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Excel are stored as doubles and not text strings.  The best is to use COUNTIFS and bookend the dates:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C38,">="&DATE(K3,1,1)",C3:C38,"<"&DATE(K3+1,1,1)")
```

But to get where the user only puts in the year we add another COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C38,">="&DATE(K3,1,1)",C3:C38,"<"&DATE(K3+1,1,1)")+COUNTIF(C3:C38,K3)
```

Comment: Perfect! This did the trick. Thank you and I'll award you the correct answer after the time restriction expires.